# Redux component not updating on state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

**Update: Apparently the bug is fixed. I never pushed a solution, so I'm still not sure what the problem/solution.**

Essentially what's going on is that I have a child component that is being passed state from the main application component. I know that works fine, as I see the default value of the state showing up properly.

When the child mounts, it fires an ajax call to fetch some data, and then fires an action to update the state value accordingly (Other packages use this fetch call and it works fine as well). I can see all of this is working as expected by taking a look at the Redux chrome devtool. It shows the action being fired, and that the state has changed from the default value to the value it fetched.

The problem is that the page still shows that default value and not the new state value. So I'm wondering if there's an issue with calling that fetch request/state update and then expecting the component to properly update. Should I pass the state as a prop one level lower and have a component that only focuses on displaying that value? It's clear that everything is working as expected, the page is just not updating when the new state value is set.

Here's the code for child component that is not updating (had to modify for privacy purposes)

```
import { bindActionCreators, Component, connect, createElement, PropTypes } from 'somePackage';

import { getStatus } from 'somedirectory';

class ChildComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);


        this.state = {
            irrelevantState: false,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchMyData();
    }

    fetchMyData() {
        const {
            boundNavActions,
        } = this.props;

        boundNavActions.getStatus();
    }

    render() {
        const {
            **stateImLookingAt**,
            irrelevantString,
            irrelevantString,
        } = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                <div styleName="irrelevantString">
                    <div styleName="irrelevantString">
                        <a
                            href={ irrelevantString }
                            aria-label={ irrelevantString }
                        >
                            <div
                                spriteSheetType="irrelevantString"
                                name={ irrelevantString }
                            />
                            //Would making this it's own component help?
                            <div styleName="thisDoesntUpdate">
                                { **stateImLookingAt** }
                            </div>
                            //Would making this it's own component help?
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ChildComponent.propTypes = {
    boundNavActions: PropTypes.object,
    cartCount: PropTypes.number,
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    boundNavActions: bindActionCreators({
        getStatus,
    }, dispatch),
});


export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ChildComponent);
```

There's not a lot going on pertaining to this state in the parent but here's a snippet

```
import { connect, createElement, PropTypes } from 'somedirectory';
import ChildComponent from 'ChildComponentPackage';

import './app.css';

const AppContainer = (props) => {
    const {
        **stateImLookingAt**,
    } = props;

    return (
        <div styleName="root">
            <ChildComponent
                **stateImLookingAt**={ **stateImLookingAt** }
            />
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    **stateImLookingAt**: state.moo.cow.**stateImLookingAt**,
});

AppContainer.propTypes = {
    **stateImLookingAt**: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppContainer);
```

Comment: need to see the Parent component; you have no state mapped to props in this component

Comment: @Tony just edited to show the parent component

Comment: @Tony just edited to show the parent component

Comment: I don't see `**stateImLookingAt**` being passed to the Child Component?

Comment: @Tony sorry, forgot to change the names there

Comment: Have you tried placing your `mapStateToProps` in the child component's `connect` call. That *should* be a valid use of `connect` but I'm curious...

Comment: So you can guarantee 100% that the store has the new value and at the path you mapped?

Comment: @Tony yeah it's definitely there. I've even had a couple other people check it out and we can't figure it out.

Comment: @MattHolland I've thought about giving that a try as well. I'll give it a try but since it already grabs the default state I can't imagine why it wouldn't  grab the updated state. I can only boil it down to the child component isn't re-rendering.

Comment: What does `boundNavActions.getStatus();` inside your `fetchData()` actually do?

Comment: @ChillyPenguin it makes an ajax request to get some data, once that request is complete it fires an action to update the state based on the the results of the request.